# Add RxJava Observer into chain depending on a condition

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm writing an Android app. At some point I need to check a result returned from a Retrofit method, and if it returns true - execute one more API request. Without Rx the logic looks like this:

```
if(api.isVip()) {
   checkIfPendingCancellation();
} else {
   JoinVipActivity.start();
}

checkIfPendingCancellation() {
    if(api.pendingCancel()) {
        YourVipIsAboutToCancelActivity.start();
    } else {
        CancelVipActivity.start();
   } 
}
```

I know it's possible to wrap everything with Rx, but not exactly sure how to do that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the API is non-RxJava based, you can do something like this:

```
Observable.just(1)
.map(v -> {
    if (api.isVip()) {
       if (api.pendingCancel()) {
           return 1;
       }
       return 2;
    }
    return 3;
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(v -> {
    if (v == 1) {
       YourVipIsAboutToCancelActivity.start();
    } else
    if (v == 2) {
       CancelVipActivity.start();
    } else {
       JoinVipActivity.start();
    }
});
```

(Remark: `Observable.just(1).map().subscribeOn()` is my personal favorite way to jumpstart an originally synchronous processing.)

Otherwise, since Retrofit does support RxJava's Observables (with a bridge I think?), you can have both API calls as `Observable<Boolean>` in which case you can use `flatMap`:

```
api.isVip()
.flatMap(b -> {
    if (b) {
        return api.pendingCancel().map(c -> c ? 1 : 2);
    }
    return Observable.just(3);
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(v -> {
    if (v == 1) {
       YourVipIsAboutToCancelActivity.start();
    } else
    if (v == 2) {
       CancelVipActivity.start();
    } else {
       JoinVipActivity.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I can use observables. And the solution is a nice one. But is it possible in theory to come up with something that doesn't require switch in onSuccess? I was looking at all those operators like 'switchCase' and 'if', but I have no idea how to use them :)

Comment: You could try those, but they are more verbose, repeats operators and perhaps less readable.